# not able to save one shipping address and one billing address in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, save, django-admin

In My Customer app i am not able to save billing and shipping address Boolean Field correctly in admin models.I will explain it with screen shot
First Step:
I can Add Multiple Address in Admin for one customer, So here i have address A and address B
When i Check on Billing address form address A and Shipping address from address B it is saved successfully [condition 1 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq7xa.png)

```
def check_billing_shipping(self):
   if self.billing_address:

       temp = Address.objects.filter(billing_address=True, customer=self.customer)
       for key in temp:
           if key.billing_address:
               key.billing_address = False
               
               key.save()


   if self.shipping_address:
       temp = Address.objects.filter(shipping_address=True, customer=self.customer)
       for key in temp:
           if (key.shipping_address):
               key.shipping_address = False
           
               key.save()

 super(Address, self).save()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Address, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    self.check_billing_shipping()
```

Same way if interchanged it i.e When i Check on Shipping address form address A and Billing address from address B and then save  it discards all checked from Address A
[after save screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzQlK.png)

we want to user to select one shipping and one billing address for one customer . Also if u don't get a question please ask again i will explain it in better way I have inline customer and address class in admin.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Out the solutions
i just added new class and ChainedForeignkey to customer address,
and inline it in admin.py so i have to seprate drop downs for shipping and 
billing address 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GMlC.png)

in case someone has same problem